# IFRAME session ID does not match until you reload the page

Tags: php, facebook, session, iframe

I have an canvas app in an `IFRAME`, I have been trying to figure out for some time why it doesn't work in `IE`. Finally I found a program called `IEWatch` which is a bit like firebug for explorer. Using this I have deduced that the `sessionID` for my app does not match on the index and the backend script. At the top of the index.php I have `session_start()` as I do on my backend script that I pass data to using ajax. If I reload the page the `sessionID` then  match's (index.php changes to match the backend.php sessionID. This does not happen in chrome.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need for IE to accept cross-browser cookies is a [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) policy header.

```
//required for IE in iframe FB environments if sessions are to work.
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Put this on top of index.php file

Comment: Top of the class! Some user have said they have had problems in Firefox also. Could this be the same problem?

Comment: shouldn't be, as firefox will allow third party sites to set cookies.